# Issues with Conditionals as well as switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to write a program to show yield for biomass in wastewater. At the beginning I want to ask some questions. I would like the code to check if what was entered matches the types of donor/acceptors I have. I thought that != would work to check if they were not that. It does not seem to work

Also the code runs if I delete everything where the  switch statements start.

To summarize

1) Why does the "!=" command not have the programs check to see if it does not match any of the names given?
2) Are my switch statements causing problems? Is there some syntax I am doing inccorect?

```
var donor = prompt("What is your electron donor?");

if (donor != "Acetate" || "Alanine" || "Benzoate" || "Citrate" || "Ethanol" || "Formate" || "Glucose" || "Glutamate" || "Glycerol" || "Glycine" || "Lactate" || "Methane" || "Methanol" || "Palmitate" || "Propionate" || "Pyruvate" || "Succinate") {
  var donor = prompt("What is your electron donor?");
} else {;
}

var acceptor = prompt("What is your electron acceptor?");

if (acceptor != "Ammonium-Nitrate" || "Ammonium-Nitrite" || "Ammonium-Nitrogen" || "Ferrous-Ferric" || "Hydrogen-H+" || "Nitrite-Nitrate" || "Nitrogen-Nitrate" || "Nitrogen-Nitrite" || "Sulfide-Sulfate" || "Sulfide-Sulfite" || "Sulfite-Sulfate" || "Sulfur-Sulfate" || "Thiosulfate-Sulfate" || "Water-Oxygen") {
  var acceptor = prompt("What is your electron acceptor?");
} else {;
}

var nitrogen = prompt("What is your Nitrogen source?");

if (nitrogen != "Ammonium" || "Nitrate") {
  var nitrogen = prompt("What is your Nitrogen source?");
} else {;
}

var carbon = prompt("What is your Carbon source?");


switch (donor) {
  case 'Acetate':
    var Gd = 27.4;
    break;
  case 'Alanine':
    var Gd = 31.37;
    break;
  case 'Benzoate':
    var Gd = 27.34;
    break;
  case 'Citrate':
    var Gd = 33.08;
    break;
  case 'Ethanol':
    var Gd = 31.18
    break;
  case 'Formate':
    var Gd = 39.19
    break;
  case 'Glucose':
    var Gd = 41.35
    break;
  case 'Glutamate':
    var Gd = 30.93
    break;
  case 'Glycerol':
    var Gd = 38.88
    break;
  case 'Glycine':
    var Gd = 39.8
    break;
  case 'Lactate':
    var Gd = 32.29
    break;
  case 'Methane':
    var Gd = 23.53
    break;
  case 'Methanol':
    var Gd = 36.84
    break;
  case 'Palmitate':
    var Gd = 27.26
    break;
  case 'Propionate':
    var Gd = 27.63;
    break;
  case 'Pyruvate':
    var Gd = 35.09;
    break;
  case 'Succinate':
    var Gd = 29.09;
    break;
   default:
    ;

}

switch (acceptor) {
  case 'Ammonium-Nitrate':
    var Ga = -35.11;
    break;
  case :'Ammonium-Nitrite':
    var Ga = -32.93 l
    break;
  case :'Ammonium-Nitrogen':
    var Ga = 26.70;
    break;
  case :'Ferrous-Ferric':
    var Ga = -74.27;
    break;
  case :'Hydrogen-H+':
    var Ga = 39.87;
    break;
  case 'Nitrite=Nitrate':
    var Ga = -41.65;
    break;
  case 'Nitrogen-Nitrate':
    var Ga = -72.2;
    break;
  case 'Nitrogen-Nitrite':
    var Ga = -92.56;
    break;
  case 'Sulfide-Sulfate':
    var Ga = 20.85;
    break;
  case ' Sulfide-Sulfite':
    var Ga = 11.03;
    break;
  case 'Sulfite-Sulfate':
    var Ga = 50.3;
    break;
  case 'Sulfur-Sulfate':
    var Ga = 19.15;
    break;
  case 'Thiosulfate-Sulfate':
    var Ga = 23.58;
    break;
  case 'Water-Oxygen':
    var Ga = -78.72;
    break;
   default:
    ;

}

var trophic = prompt("Is this process Heterotrophic or Autotrophic?")

if (trophic = "Autotrophic") {
  var Gp = 113.8;
} else if (trophic = "Heterotrophic") {
  var Gp = 35.09 - Gd;
} else {
  var trophic = prompt("Is this process Heterotrophic or Autotrophic?");
}


if (nitrogen = 'Ammonium') {
  var Gpc = 18.8;
} else {
  var Gpc = 13.4;
}


var epsilon = prompt("What is your value for epsilon? (Assume 0.6 if you do not know)")

if (Gp > 0) {
  var n = 1
} else {
  var n = -1
}

var Gr = Ga - Gd

var A = -((Gp / (epsilon ^ n)) + (Gpc / epsilon)) / (epsilon * Gr)

var fs = 1 / (1 + A)

var fe = 1 - fs

var Y = fs / 1.42
```

Comment: Delete all your blank "else statements" these `else {;}` are not needed

Comment: kill switch. `var Ga={'Ammonium-Nitrate':-35.11, 'Ferrous-Ferric': -74.27 ...}[acceptor];`

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue:

```
if (donor != "Acetate" || "Alanine" || "Benzoate" || ...
```

When checking for the value of `donor`, you have to check it for each individual item.

```
if (donor != "Acetate" || donor != "Alanine" || donor != "Benzoate" || ...
```

This, however, is still a bit of an unwieldy solution. I would personally go with something like this:

```
var allowedDonors = "acetate alanine benzonate ...";
if( ~allowedDonors.indexOf(donor) ) { 
  // Code handling a valid donor
}
```

Though even this isn't perfect, as it fails if the input isn't exactly as spelled in the `allowedDonors` string, but it's a place to start.

You also do not need the empty `else {}` blocks.

As for your switch statement (and a few other places), you're declaring `var`s in the section of code that's supposed to determine their value. That's fine for some things, but since you want to use those variables later, it's best to declare them outside of your `if` and `switch` statements:

```
var carbon = prompt("What is your Carbon source?");

var Gd;

switch (donor) {
  case 'Acetate':
    Gd = 27.4;
    break;
  case 'Alanine':
    Gd = 31.37;
    break;

...
```

This way you can use them later in your code (like you try to at the very bottom).

Keep in mind that the `^` operator in Javascript is not used for exponents -- you need `Math.pow(base, exponent)` for that.

Lower in the code, you're comparing using `=`, which is the assignment operator. Compare two values using `==`, such as here: `if( nitrogen = "Ammonium")` should be `if( nitrogen == "Ammonium")`.

Comment: Goodness gracious. I'm going to edit my post and see if I can capture a few.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help

Answer (score 0):

Make a function and send the parameter you want... so your switch will be 100% more efficent
for example:
do all your if statements and code then add this;

```
condorSwitch(condor);
        function condorSwitch(condor){
            //your switch statements code
                }
```